# Android AMR-WB encoding issue

Tags: android-8.0-oreo, android-mediacodec, audiorecord, amr

I am trying to use AMR-WB encoding feature of Android Oreo to encode live microphone capture PCM using AudioRecorder. The encoding works without any exception but the encoded voice data seems not perfect. Here is how the code looks like:

My AudioRecord settings:

```
        int audioSource = MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC;
        int sampleRateInHz = 8000;
        int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
        int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
        int bufferSizeInBytes = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat);
        AudioRecord ar = new AudioRecord(audioSource, sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat, bufferSize);
```

MediaCodec settings:

```
        MediaCodec mc = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AMR_WB);
        MediaFormat mf = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AMR_WB, 4000, 1);
        mf.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 6600);
        mc.configure(mf, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mc.start();
```

Recording loop:

```
                    int srcLength = ar.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); // reads 640 bytes


                    int ibufferId = mc.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
                    ByteBuffer ibuffer = mc.getInputBuffer(ibufferId);
                    ibuffer.position();
                    ibuffer.put(buffer, 0, srcLength);
                    mc.queueInputBuffer(ibufferId, 0, srcLength, 0, 0);
                    int obufferId = mc.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, -1);
                    if (obufferId == INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                        obufferId = mc.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, -1);
                    }
                    ByteBuffer obuffer = mc.getOutputBuffer(obufferId); // has 18 bytes                        

                    mc.releaseOutputBuffer(obufferId, false);
```

If I write the output bytes (`obuffer`) to file and try to play it using VLC player, it plays the audio faster than normal.

Is there any possible solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. The source PCM sampling rate must be 16000 for legible AMR audio. I don't know why this is so.

Comment: It's simply part of the spec for this codec, that it only ever operates on 16 kHz data.

Comment: @mstorsjo, can you please share a link to support the reason. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Multi-Rate_Wideband - "All modes are sampled at 16 kHz", "The AMR wideband speech format shall be supported in 3G multimedia services when wideband speech working at 16 kHz sampling frequency is supported."